# How do I create a simple animation for use in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, animator, animation-controller

I'm trying to create a simple shrinking animation for use in Unity. The goal is to create an animation that shrinks the object to be 0.1 scale.

I've created an Animator Controller with an empty state, and an Animation, and assigned the Animation into the Animator Controller's empty state's "Motion" slot, but I have no idea what to do next. This is what the inspector looks like on the Animation:

[image: Inspector]

When I click "Open", nothing happens. There doesn't seem to be any area to edit the animation.

I have no idea where to start, sorry if the question isn't detailed enough.

Comment: You probably don't want to use an animation controller / animator component for this. An [animation component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) should do just fine. Have you tried working through the [docs about creating an animation clip](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-CreatingANewAnimationClip.html)?

Comment: I was able to figure it out by following that guide, thanks. The solution is to make an animation using the "Animation" window instead of just making a new file.

Comment: Don't forget to post your solution as an answer if you solved your problem!